# How to add a button to a running Windows GUI program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, user-interface, mfc

Now I want to dynamically modify the GUI of a running WINDOWS program(assume this program is written in win32 API/MFC), for example, add a button to it's specific position.

But I'm not familiar with WINDOWS GUI programming.

So I want to ask if there is any normal way to implement this feature using win32 API or MFC.

If not, do I need any hacking tips?

Comment: [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx).

Comment: thanks..it's helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You can `dynamically` create any Windows component by utilizing the [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) function when processing (for example) a [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) message inside your [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) callback function. Or any other message for that matter. Provided that you have a button with an ID of `IDC_BUTTON` you can create a new button when clicked.

```
case WM_COMMAND: // process commands
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON: //check for our button ID
            HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
                L"BUTTON", // predefined class name
                L"OK", // button text 
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
                10, // x position 
                10, // y position 
                75, // width
                24, // height
                hWnd, // parent handle
                (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2, // button ID
                hInst, // module instance
                NULL); // lparam, pointer not needed
            break;
        }
```